# Generate jHipster standalone server app without security

Tags: java, rest, security, jhipster

My understanding is that it is not possible to generate a jHipster app without any security, as is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4763).

I generated a server app (using jHipster version 4.9.0) using the following command by selecting the default JWT security:

```
jhipster --skip-client --with-entities --skip-user-management
```

However, upon running above app, I can call my GET api's directly (from a rest client such as postman or even directly from the browser), **without providing any Authorization header** (aka the JWT token). **Essentially, security is disabled.**

Could this be a bug? What am I missing here? Can someone please shed some light on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's a bug, `SecurityConfiguration.java` has not been generated because of wrong logic, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/files.js#L257

```
        /* Skip the code below for --skip-user-management */
        if (this.skipUserManagement && (this.applicationType !== 'monolith' || this.authenticationType !== 'oauth2')) return;
```

Please report it on github.

Comment: Accepted your answer. However, tt would be nice to have an option to skip security/auth for generating a mock server. I have submitted the following: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6689